Rollback during Dataload Failure ADF
Today we had an error on STAGE when receiving an order - due to a “lost connection”.
My idea was then to set this “repeat” to 3:
Please see the screenshot
Now the question is, what happens if it has already read and written half and then repeats. presumably it then writes the data twice, because it won't do a rollback. Or it writes automatically from where it failed?
example., If the connection was loast after writing 100 records to the destination table, retrying will start to write from 101st record or will it start from first?
Appreciate your help!
Thanks

The copy activity retry will start from the beginning. It means, in the case of files, it will overwrite the target file and in the case of database tables, it will append the source data to the target table just like the original behavior of copy activity.
If your write behavior in the copy activity sink is insert, then it will append all source rows to the target. This will create duplicates in your target table.
To avoid it, follow the below methods.

Have an Upsert write behavior in your copy activity so that it checks every source row before copying it to the target table.
Enable Fault tolerance in copy activity to skip the duplicates.
Have a staging table in between the source and target tables and have a pre-copy script of truncate table temp_table for that temp table. This will truncate all rows in the temp table before every copy to it and duplicates will be eliminated. After that copy from this temp table to your target table.

You can check this similar ask by @Pratik Somaiya.
